# Прокрутка в таблице

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы шапка таблицы оставалась на месте а содержимое прокручивалось при прокрутке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сори, как то странно работает тег для кода, качай http://depositfiles.com/files/gzh29pti3

Оценить не забудь ;) удачи

**Добавлено**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function removeClassName (elem, className) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(className, "").trim();
}

function addCSSClass (elem, className) {
    removeClassName (elem, className);
    elem.className = (elem.className + " " + className).trim();
}

String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/, "" );
}

function stripedTable() {
    if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {  
        var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
        if (!allTables) { return; }

        for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
            if (allTables[i].className.match(/[\w\s ]*scrollTable[\w\s ]*/)) {
                var trs = allTables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++) {
                    removeClassName(trs[j], 'alternateRow');
                    addCSSClass(trs[j], 'normalRow');
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < trs.length; k += 2) {
                    removeClassName(trs[k], 'normalRow');
                    addCSSClass(trs[k], 'alternateRow');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() { stripedTable(); }
-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

/* begin some basic styling here                     */
body {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    font: normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0
}

table, td, a {
    color: #000;
    font: normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

h1 {
    font: normal normal 18px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0
}

h2 {
    font: normal normal 16px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0
}

h3 {
    font: normal normal 13px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #008000;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0
}
/* end basic styling                                 */

/* define height and width of scrollable area. Add 16px to width for scrollbar          */
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px
}

/* Reset overflow value to hidden for all non-IE browsers. */
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 756px
}

/* define width of table. IE browsers only                 */
div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}

/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                        */
html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 756px
}

/* set table header to a fixed position. WinIE 6.x only                                       */
/* In WinIE 6.x, any element with a position property set to relative and is a child of       */
/* an element that has an overflow property set, the relative value translates into fixed.    */
/* Ex: parent element DIV with a class of tableContainer has an overflow property set to auto */
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

/* set THEAD element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

/* make the TH elements pretty */
thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
thead.fixedHeader a, thead.fixedHeader a:link, thead.fixedHeader a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
/* WARNING: swapping the background on hover may cause problems in WinIE 6.x   */
thead.fixedHeader a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%
}

/* define the table content to be scrollable                                              */
/* set TBODY element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
/* induced side effect is that child TDs no longer accept width: auto                     */
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

/* make TD elements pretty. Provide alternating classes for striping the table */
/* http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebratables/                             */
tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

/* define width of TH elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* Add 16px to last TH for scrollbar padding. All other non-IE browsers. */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th {
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th {
    width: 316px
}

/* define width of TD elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                            */
html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 200px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td {
    width: 240px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td + td {
    width: 300px
}
-->
</style>
</head><body>

<h1>Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header</h1>
<h2>Using CSS to allow scrolling within a single HTML table</h2>

<div><br></div>

<h2>The Big 4 Version</h2>
<h3>Basic CSS Browser Filtering</h3>

<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <th><a href="#">Header 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Header 2</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Header 3</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="scrollContent">
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>End of Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div><br></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: мсье знает толк в извращениях...

Comment: ого, спасибо, от обьема я офигел, ща буду разбираться))